# ARKIT how to get world origin transform

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I guess a simple question, how do I get the current sessions world origin transform? There is a function setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: matrix_float4x4) but no getWorldOrigin() in ARSession, but I need to know the current origin, because setWorldOrigin is a relative transform. How to get it?

Another thing I'd like to know, ARSession is sometimes updating the world origin on it's own, is there handler to know when this is happening?

Comment: As per your part (b) to your question - the AR world is only perfect under the conditions of: perfect lighting, minor movements on the camera, and various objects on the screen (in real world). Being that this does not happen most of the time, the origin is bound to move. Expect it to move, at least until the user has settled out everything the camera sees; even then, that’s not always enough. Thus, the entire ARScene may move

Comment: I know it may move, question b) was, is there a handler where I can detect when this happens.

Comment: Not to my knowledge - I mean imagine if the center of the Earth moved; everything would also move with it. You can't just put stuff "back" without putting the Earth back. But the Earth thinks it is still at the center - so in essence, to my understanding, nothing you can do. At least the way I think about it

Comment: I just find it odd that there exists a setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: matrix_float4x4) function, when you cant access the current world origin to do absolute transforms and also cant recognize when the transformation you performed on world origin with this function is overriden by auto updates of ARSession.

Comment: So the way I have used that function was so I could center other objects. Say - I would place the origin 2 feet in front of where I was currently, then I could use that as my origin. It made my math easier. I mean end all be all, the origin is generally hidden and users dont see it. It’s more of how you want to do math

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same issue @chris

Comment: @DanielTovesson sadly no, it seems it is not possible.